# Understanding elegant prime number tester

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and testing myself with some questions. One that came up was to test whether a user inputted number was prime or not. Easy enough, but one person came up with a single line of code as a solution.

```
import math

num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 2 "))

if sum([True if num%factor == 0 else False for factor in ([2] + list(range(3,int(math.sqrt(num)),2)))]):
  print("Number is composite")
else:
  print("Number is prime")
```

I understand part of it: the `if` statement is True if (number/iterations) gives a remainder of 0, else False, where the only iterations that need to be checked are 2 -> sqrt(number) skipping all even numbers.

However, I can't work out how to sum operator at the start of the if statement works. I assume it operates on the True(1)/False(0) statements, but how does this interaction play out and how does it affect the if/else statements?

Comment: In Python, all numbers except for 0 are treated as `True`. That's how it affects the if/else statements.

Comment: [`True` and `False`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#bool) are, in fact, integers in Python. Therefore, the `sum` function returns a non-zero result when _any_ of the conditions are true.

Comment: Also - here is the documentation for the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sum) function

Comment: totally should  have used [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) though...

Comment: @Adam.Er8 The `True if xxx else False` is also redundant, so the `sum([True if num%factor == 0 else False for ...])` can be readily simplified to `any([num%factor == 0 for ...])` (or even `all([num%factor for ...])`)

Comment: And since `all` and `any` work with generators as well, the square brackets can be omitted, i.e. `any(num%factor == 0 for ...)`.